# Secure way to back up systemd logs

Tags: arch-linux, logs, systemd, backup, raspberry-pi

I have arch linux installed on a raspberry pi and want to start backing up my logs regularly to some external write-once media. It'll probably be a CD, but I'm not sure yet, and it will probably happen over my local network (I have an old laptop I'm using as another server that has a CD drive). I don't want to use only a system backup because I want to add an extra layer of redundancy, and because I don't want to use a write-once medium for my system backups.

I have a couple questions:

1. Are there any guides out for using systemd's logging for security purposes (ie, securing logs against attackers)?
2. What are the downsides to storing logs on a CD instead of a Tape Drive?
3. Are there tools for comparing two systemd logs and checking for discrepancies at certain dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing logs on a CD or Tape Drive don’t seem to be an efficient , and usable solution. Instead you can set-up a separate , secure server machine (or may be a virtual machine ) , to which you can send logs. You can install log-stash on that server that will filter the logs for you (what type of data you want to keep and what you want to discard).

For efficient storage and retrieval you can install Elastic-search that integrates with log-stash. For viewing data (and checking for discrepancies), you can use Kibana.

On the client side you can either write your own script that send the log to the log server (logstash+elasticsearch+kibana) or you can use file-beat that monitors log files and sends data to log-stash.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was fairly typical for larger organizations to store logs on write only media, but I don't know much about system administration. Are there other write-once mediums besides CD and Tape Drives that I could use? I know it'd be easier/more efficient to use a separate, secured server with a regular hard drive, but I'd kind of like to use a medium that can't be altered remotely. I'm kind of paranoid about someone breaking into my system, changing the logs, and remaining undetected.

Comment: you can configure security for elastic-search so that it will accept writes only from your logs , and not from anywhere else. it can be on your local LAN and will not be accessible to outer world , plus you can encrypt the communication to log server using https , plus a user-name and password.

Comment: Ok, thanks, good to know. For a sane person, that'd be good enough. I'd still like to use a write once media to be extra sure it can't be altered. I'll probably hack something together, get really frustrated, then move to a saner solution like the one you've offered.

Comment: you can use CD or tape but that is not a scalable solution.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I'm not intending to scale up that much/use the pi a whole lot, so I'm not as concerned about that as I otherwise would be. It sounds like the main issue with using a CD or tape drive is the scalability then, not the setup? Should that be relatively straightfoward?

Comment: yes , its kind of manual task , of writing data on CDs , and when something bad happens , or when you need that data back , you ll have to look for the CD. or may be you lose the CD. :)